# Don't Change Text Color on mouseover wicket

Tags: java, html, wicket

I create an simple Label in wicket, but when I go with the mouse over the Label, the text color turns to blue color. It shouldn't turn to any color as the original. How I can organize it, that the Label remains her original color?

```
final Label<String> textLabel = new Label<String>("textHtml", new
ResourceModel("textXML"));
textLabel .setEscapeModelStrings(false);
form.add(textLabel);
```

Comment: How does the html of that label look like and what css rules apply to it and are there special css rules for :hover? This is almost certainly something that is defined in the CSS styles you are using and not something that has to do with wicket.

Comment: I solve it. Thanks.

Comment: I have set the text which is in xml directly in html with the xml key specifikation, without any declaration in java.